# MySQL filter uniqueness based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I am wondering if it is possible in MySQL to make sure double rows are impossible if two columns match. I am working on a table which represents followers, so it looks like this:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| followID | followerID | followingID |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| 1        | 1          | 2           |
| 2        | 1          | 3           |
| 3        | 2          | 1           |
| 4        | 3          | 1           |
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Basically means user 1 is following user 2 and 3 and user 2 and 3 follow user 1 back. Now I want to avoid double results in here, so I want uniqueness based on followerID and followingID. Currently I run two queries to check if the row already exists (with a SELECT) and only if it doesn't I allow a new INSERT.

However, I would like a second security measure where it is impossible to INSERT if it already exists. So I want to avoid this:

```
+----------+------------+-------------+
| followID | followerID | followingID |
+----------+------------+-------------+
| 1        | 1          | 2           |
| 2        | 1          | 3           |
| 3        | 2          | 1           |
| 4        | 3          | 1           |
| 5        | 2          | 1           | *
| 6        | 1          | 3           | *
+----------+------------+-------------+
```

Row 5 and 6 should never be possible to INSERT because they already are in the table. Can this be achieved in MySQL or do I have to check it on the server?

Comment: Just add a unique key on (`followerID`, `followingID`)

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Follower 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [yourConstraintName]
  UNIQUE(followerID, followingID)
```